# Asymptotics of expected max of gaussians

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, solution-verification, asymptotics

Let $w_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathcal N(0, 1)$. Show that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E \max_i^n |w_i| /\sqrt{\log{2n}} = 1$$

**my attempt**

First, recall the well known upper bound: $\mathbb E \max |w_i| \leq \sqrt{2\log n}$.

Next, we show an asymptotic lower bound, after which the result will follow by sandwiching. By Markov's inequality, for all positive $t$:

$$\mathbb E \max |w_i| \geq t\mathbb P (\max |w_i| \geq t)$$

By independence:

$$\mathbb P (\max |w_i| \geq t) = 1- (1-2\mathbb P(w_i \geq t))^n$$

Taking $t = \sqrt{2\log n}$ all that remains to show is that $(1-2\mathbb P(w_i \geq \sqrt{2 \log n}))^n$ goes to $0$. It is sufficient to show that there is some $N$ such that for all $m \geq N$  we have that $2\mathbb P(w_i \geq \sqrt{2\log m}) < 1$. This is obviously true since $\mathbb P(w_i \geq u)$ is decreasing in $u$ and has minimum $0$.

**my question**

Is there a mistake in my proof? It is surprisingly simpler than other solutions I have seem, so I expect some issue. See the solution for part (c) here: https://high-dimensional-statistics.github.io/2020/08/27/exercise-2.11.html

Comment: Here lies the mistake: If you have sequence $(1-x_n)^n$ (in your case $x_n = 2\mathbb P(w_1 \ge \sqrt{2\ln n})$, then it is not sufficient to show that $x_n < 1$ (neither that $x_n \to 0$) for $(1-x_n)^n \to 0$ to hold. Indeed, if $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then $(1-x_n)^n \to e^{-1}$.  I believe that your approach can be made valid if you use gaussian estimate $(\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t^3})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \le \mathbb P(w_1 \ge t) \le \frac{1}{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$.

Comment: Yes, it works, but we at first need to separate from $2$, i.e. we show that $\liminf_n \frac{\mathbb E \max|w_i|}{\sqrt{(2-\varepsilon) \ln n}} \ge 1$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and then conclude.

Comment: I should have know i had a mistake where I used the word "obvious". Thank you! I will try to rework it.

Comment: It is sufficient to show that $(1-2\mathbb P(w_i \geq \sqrt{2 \log n}))^n$ has an upper bound that goes to $0$. Applying the first half of your mills ratio type bound along with $1-x \leq e^{-x}$ we can show that the exponent goes to $-\infty$ using L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, no since the answers there made a different mistake than I did. I asked about proof verification, of course I can find a proof on the internet without much trouble, but here I was asking about my specific proof attempt.

Comment: @dmh My mistake.